# Plotting data in a multi-view layout consisting of discrete and continuous data on arbitrary, discrete axes

Tags: vega-lite

I'm trying to combine a discrete dataset and its mean into one chart with Vega-Lite.

The problem is that the axes must be within a fixed domain, and layering over the mean aggregate data messes up these axes. In the picture below, the top x-axis is created by the mean aggregate data layer and the lower x-axis by the domain constrained one.

I need the domain constraints because the axis must always show the minimum and maximum value of the domain *and* the special, discrete intervals (10 and 50 in this example). The data will always be one of these discrete values.

How can I make sure both sets of data are plotted on the domain-constrained axes?

[image]

This is the simplified code ([and here it is in the Vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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)).

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "",
  "datasets": {
    "data": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 100, "size": 1},
      {"x": 50, "y": 100, "size": 1},
      {"x": 50, "y": 0, "size": 1}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {"name": "data"},
      "mark": {"type": "point", "filled": true, "color": "#a7f3d0"},
      "encoding": {
        "size": {"field": "size", "type": "ordinal", "legend": null},
        "x": {
          "field": "x",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "title": "",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 10, 50, 100]}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "y",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "title": "",
          "scale": {"domain": [100, 50, 10, 0]}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {"name": "data"},
      "mark": {"type": "point", "shape": "diamond"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x", "aggregate": "mean", "title": ""},
        "y": {"field": "y", "aggregate": "mean", "title": ""}
      }
    }
  ]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried one variation where the axis of both the layers are in sync and have a max range value as 100. Refer the [link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289IpVJMSCHEwQ0oZUZSoA2qAAeaAAxKAnmgCMLtyAg0AF5w3gC+Ck5oYn6eqD5+AcFhESDOqNEerkqJIXHhkagATDFoxdlBuV6hALrhIIJI7nDqaA6GxpYgskgIue0odcjqANadmO44fThsNLKYBgBmNIKCcMpomOoMcEpQbIJsLegAxEgA7AsAzMouIHVwsnvKs2SdOZ1LcILr6O9K45M0CBDs9uoIDKsyA8frIGCs6mlQJ9vkDnP8Jn0AI4MJBzOhGGikAw6TCrIEGaBIMmoKxsZCzACySDS8VCdViSJoXx+IE86MB6GxuJJBKJ-zo1JAdzZKWsHRpXR6fTlAyUQ1GCoBUxmcwpMCQApUNB6cnW90ebFBrwViJAyJ5aJASDIZHUfEwfV6uOJEr6xIxQKFeOMOiJ7I+XJR6D5TpdbooHqBXvk4tJfqUzJoFlQsJW-KxOODopCbJqSjdMkERIVmezBRAs1Uk1kql1mXQjbgzdb8xlID2siW1tAxC5AHc3ps2MM+sIyFgIA0Pa7GtLQkA) or below code and let me know if this was helpful.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "",
  "datasets": {
    "data": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 100, "size": 1},
      {"x": 50, "y": 100, "size": 1},
      {"x": 50, "y": 0, "size": 1},
      {"x": 20, "y": 20, "size": 1}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {"name": "data"},
      "mark": {"type": "point", "filled": true, "color": "#a7f3d0"},
      "encoding": {
        "size": {"field": "size", "type": "ordinal", "legend": null},
        "x": {
          "field": "x",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "",
          "scale": {"domainMax": 100}
        },
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative", "title": ""}
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {"name": "data"},
      "mark": {"type": "point", "shape": "diamond"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "x",
          "aggregate": "mean",
          "title": "",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "y",
          "aggregate": "mean",
          "title": "",
          "axis": null,
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"axis": {"x": "independent", "y": "independent"}},
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": "lightslategray"}}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out. There is still the issue of the discrete domains. I would like the chart to have [0, 10, 50, 100] evenly spaced out on both axes. 
The x-y data is always one of these numbers (that's why they're "ordinal") but the means are not (they're continuous; "quantitative"). I want them to be mapped on the same axes as the x/y values.